# Bypassing ASP.NET "validaterequest" for stored XSS attack

Tags: html, asp.net

Lots of research has been done but I have not had any success. I have already checked the following links and many more.

https://infosecauditor.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/bypassing-asp-net-validaterequest-for-script-injection-attacks/

http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/06/bypassing-aspnet-request-validation.html

Is there any way that how to bypass asp validation request for storing **XSS attack.?**

In above link, unicode characters are to be inserted and then popup on rendering time.

Is there any possibilities to execute script by unicode characters?

Comment: Is your requirement to bypass asp.net ValidateRequest functionality which is by default enabled for ASP.NET request.?

Comment: yes. my requirement to store XSS by unicode

Comment: To encode your content to make it XSS safe, encode the string, like :
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(inputString);

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to bypass ASP.NET ValidateRequest functionality which is by default enabled for ASP.NET; then in the aspx page directive add the validateRequest attribute and set it to false. Se the code below:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

If your requirement is to make the input string XSS safe, encode the input string:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(inputString);
```